# Training deep learning model in Jupyterlab desktop

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter, reinforcement-learning, jupyter-lab

I am trying to train my Deep reinforcement learning based model using jupyterlab desktop. When the training passes 9hrs, the desktop app frozen and the model is not training.(I checked the task manager as well). Is this because of memory limitation, Do i have to change any settings?

I am expecting how fix this issue changing the memory limitation setting in Jupyterlab. Can anyone help me on finding the solution for this?

Comment: Quick question why are you using jupyter lab?

Comment: Probably its a memory issue, please use Google Collab